# What is the difference between 織機(しょっき) and 機 (はた)?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, wago-and-kango

Does **織機** mean the device, while **機** means the concept?

Or maybe one of them is more formal than the other?

Comment: What has your dictionary told you so far?

Comment: They both mean "loom", and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both refer to the device of weaving, but modern automatic power-looms are usually called 織機 (しょっき) or 織布機 (しょくふき). Traditional, manual looms are typically called 機 (はた) or 機織り機 (はたおりき) in novels and fairy tales. In academic contexts they're called 織機 anyway (see [Japanese Wikipedia on 織機](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B9%94%E6%A9%9F)).